# Performance degrades after adding solr nodes

Tags: performance, solr, datastax-enterprise

I'm having an odd issue in where I set up a DSE 4.0 cluster with 1 Cassandra node and 1 Solr node (using DseSimpleSnitch) and performance is great. If I add additional nodes to have 3 Cassandra nodes and 3 Solr nodes, then the performance of my Solr queries goes downhill dramatically. Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I have basically all default options for DSE and have tried wiping all data and recreating everything from scratch several times with the same result. I've also tried creating the keyspace with replication factors of 1 and 2 with the same results.
Maybe my use case is a bit odd but I'm using Solr for OLTP type queries(via SolrJ with binary writers/readers) which is why the performance is critical. With a very light workload of say 5 clients making very simple Solr queries the response times go up about 50% from a single Solr node to 3 Solr nodes with only a few hundred small documents seeded for my test(~25ms to ~50ms). The response times get about 2 to 3 times slower with 150 clients against 3 nodes compared to a single node. The response times for Cassandra are unchanged, its only the Solr queries that get slower.
Could there be something with my configuration causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Solr queries need to fan out to cover the full range of keys for the column family. So, when you go from one node to three nodes, it should be no surprise that the total query time would rise to three times a query that can be satisfied with a single node.

You haven't mentioned the RF for the Search DC.

For more complex queries, the fan out would give a net reduction in query latency since only a fraction of the total query time would occur on each node, while for a small query the overhead of the fanout and aggregation of query results dwarfs the time to do the actual Solr core query.

Generally, Cassandra queries tend to be much simpler than Solr queries, so they are rarely comparable.

Comment: Ok thanks I was afraid that might be the problem, which may render my design as a bad idea. My RF for the Solr DC is the same as the Cassandra DC so I've tried values of 1 and 2. In thinking about this some more maybe this is part of my problem/solution and I should create separate keyspaces for my Cassandra accessed data and my Solr accessed data. I'm new to this stuff and hadn't really thought about that before.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. After noticing the documentation mentioning not to use virtual nodes for Solr nodes (and not saying why) I checked my configuration and noticed I was using virtual nodes. I changed my configuration to not use virtual nodes and the performance issue disappeared. I also upgraded from 4.0.0. to 4.0.2 at the same time but I'm pretty sure it was the virtual nodes causing the problem.

Comment: Why vnodes are bad for Solr nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174455/dse-solr-nodes-and-vnodes