# Disabling virtual nodes in an existing Solr DC

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I have an existing cluster with the following topology:

1. DC Cassandra: 2 nodes
2. DC Solr: 5 nodes

All of the nodes currently use vnodes. I want to disable vnodes in the Solr DC for [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174455/dse-solr-nodes-and-vnodes).

According to [this document](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployConfigRep.html), to disable vnodes:

> 1. In the cassandra.yaml file, set num_tokens to 1
> 2. Uncomment the initial_token property and set it to 1 or to the value of a generated token for a multi-node cluster.

Is this all that I need to do? (no repair, no cleanup, no anything?) Seems too good to be true for me.

As for token assignment, should I use the python code [found here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html) (for Murmur3) or should I reuse one of the existing tokens from the vnodes that the node currently has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to disable vnodes is to do:  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction_t.html
in the reverse.  Make a new Solr dc with vnodes off and switch over to it.

Comment: How do I do this with DseSimpleSnitch? DC is auto-selected by DSE depending on the node type; so if I boot up a new Solr node, it will be assigned to the existing Solr DC.

Comment: You have to change away from DseSimpleSnitch to a different snitch first.  Like PropertyFileSnitch or GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

Comment: Can you expound on this please? 1. Should I only change the snitch in the new DC or in all DCs? 2. How should I name the new DC? I'm pretty sure that I can't name it as "Solr" because the auto-generated DC is already named as such. 3. Since I can't name the new DC as "Solr" anymore, does it mean that I can't change back to DseSimpleSnitch after this? (unless naming the DC is allowed)

Comment: Typo in last sentence: should  be "renaming the DC"