# Measures to be taken after reducing vnodes(num_tokens) from 256 to 32

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are running DSE in Search(Solr) mode with vnodes enabled. Instead of disabling vnodes, decided to control the **num_tokens** value to 32 from the default 256 in cassandra.yaml.

> After reducing the num tokens value, what other measures are to be
>   taken on production cluster? like balancing the tokens, data, etc

Version: DSE 4.8

Answer (score 1):

You can't do balancing with vnodes but you shouldn't have to. By virtue of statistics you should have a pretty even distribution of data across your nodes even with 32 vnodes. And fewer vnodes will give you better search performance.

Also keep an eye on CASSANDRA-7032, this should let us go to even lower `num_tokens` without sacrificing data distribution.

Comment: Thank you. So just changing the num_tokens to 32 and restarting the cassandra service should distribute the data and balance the cluster right? worried if there would be imbalance with the data sizes in the nodes.

Comment: No you can't change it on a live cluster

Comment: You'll have to spin up a new DC with 32 and  once you've reolicated, decommission the old one

Comment: Thanks again. So, when u say as new DC, do I need to go for a separate dedicated hardware for the new DC or Can I use the same servers where DSE Solr is launched and try with a different DC name from earlier?

Comment: Do you have data in the cluster that you need to keep it is it a new cluster?

Comment: Yes. Everything is in production. We do have data in the cluster and wanted to have to have the same in the new DC as well..! I would like to reduce num_tokens to 32 from 256 in the live cluster. Can't this be done?

Comment: Yes you'll need a new data center temporarily, this implies another set of hardware for the time it takes to replicate. It's a logical data center not necessarily in another location. How many nodes / how much data oer node do you have?

Comment: We have 2 datacenters and 3nodes in each DC. Data size is around 20GB (in total). Everything is on AWS. We don't want to have any change with the DNS, ip addresses etc. Can this be achieved? When num_tokens updated to 32 and streamed the data in the new DC, can we move back to old DC by following the same process and delete the new DC once the replication is done? Just for changing the vnodes number(to 32) , do we really need to request for new hardware? It requires lot of effort, I believe.

Comment: Yes, num_tokens is really a decision you should have made up front and now you can only change it the hard way. Think about it, this will essentially require most of your data to move. That's why the new DC makes the most sense and there will never be a simpler change num_tokens feature. Changing your contact points in the app layer should be trivial if you're using a DataStax driver.

Comment: I got it. Can you please finalize the rework? So, since we already have 2 Datacenters, in order for this work to be done, we will need to have 2 more new datacenters and push the data. Can you please list out the steps to be performed to work on this? I am following this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165228/how-to-disable-vnodes-in-an-existing-cassandra-cluster?rq=1